# Mysql get unique data from two tables of unequal fields

Tags: data-retrieval

I have two tables that store IP numbers. The number of columns of each table is different. I need to get the unique IP's that are in both tables. Given table structures of

```
    table A {
    ip_number int(64)   UNSIGNED,
    str varchar(20)
    status tinyint(1),
    name varchar(10).
    address varchar9100)
    }   
    table B {
    ip_number int(64)   UNSIGNED,
    cnt int,
    last datetime
    }
```

with entries like

```
    table A {
     123456789,
     'aaa',
     1,
     'bob',
     '123' 
    }
    table B {
     234567890,
     1,
     2022-02-20,
     
     345678901
     2,
     2021-03-03
     }
```

I want a result like (numbers made up)

```
    123.34.45
    123.34.46
    123.34.47
```

I've tried a number of variations found here but none worked. This one runs without failures but doesn't return any results:

```
    SELECT INET_NTOA(ip_number) as ip_number, a.str, a.status FROM table A as a
    join
    (SELECT INET_NTOA(ip_number) as ip_number FROM table B ) as b
    order by ip_number
```

I also tried using union but, apparently, that only works if the column numbers are the same. Would someone explain how to do this, please?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs to be able to do this, I got it working with this code:

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(a.ip_number) as ip_number, a.str, a.status FROM table A as a
union
SELECT INET_NTOA(b.ip_number) as ip_number, Null as str, Null as status FROM table B as b 
order by ip_number
```